# Font in Terminal looks corrupted

Tags: shell

Hello I have the next problem, Im a new Linux user and I don't know what I do so my shell look so different as default one.
and the letter are kind of united, I'ved seen some similar posts but any of them worked.
also: sorry for my broken english.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue may be caused by two things:

1) you have modified your system font settings and have set some proportional font (i.e. OpenSans Regular, in which different letters have different widths) as your system monospace font. Solution: install [elementary tweaks](https://github.com/elementary-tweaks/elementary-tweaks), go to `System Settings > Tweaks > Fonts` and choose any monospace font (i.e. Roboto Mono Regular) to be your system monospace font.

2) you have messed only your Terminal's font setting. To fix it in elementary OS 5, run this command:

```
sudo gsettings set io.elementary.terminal.settings font 'RobotoMono-Regular 10'
```

Comment: It just doesn't worked I'ved tried both.

Comment: 1. Did you reboot your PC afterwards? 2. Have you been experiencing this issue all the time since the fresh system installation, or only recently?

Comment: yes, every time and no, recently yesterday and the commands to change font doesn't works it stays equal.

Comment: yes, every time I made a change, and no since yesterday. also I've tried reinstalling elementary tweaks, and the font doesn't seems to change and the size.

Comment: I already fix it making a teawks new instalalion rebooting and using the  fix font elementary code you gave me thanks.